# Add/Remove Inputs and Shift IDs with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I know there are a lot of answers to dynamically adding/removing inputs, but I haven't seen anything about shifting the IDs. I want to dynamically add/remove inputs with Javascript. The inputs must all have unique IDs, and if the input is removed, all the IDs must shift in place to a 1,2,3 format.

For instance, if I have:
1 = Bread
2 = Milk
3 = Cheese

And I want to remove Milk and add Apples, I should get:
1 = Bread
2 = Cheese
3 = Apples

I have tried a couple approaches, but I'm still stuck. Unfortunately, the ids are getting duplicated, and they aren't shifting as I'd hoped. This is what I'm getting:
1 = Bread
3 = Cheese
3 = Apples

The first approach I tried was just id++ and id--, but obviously that doesn't work because it doesn't take into account existing ids. The next approach was putting everything into an array, then making id = index, but I seem to be having the same problem, and I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

```
let id = 0;
let groceryList = document.getElementById("groceryList");
var groceryItems = [];

/*Make it easier to add lots of attrs*/
function setAttributes(el, attrs){
     for(var key in attrs) {
          el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
     }
}

function addItem(){
let itemId = "item" + id;

/*Create Fieldset*/
var groceryItem = document.createElement("fieldset");
groceryItem.id = itemId;

/*Create Label*/
var inputLabel = document.createElement("label");
var labelText = document.createTextNode("Item " + id);
inputLabel.appendChild(labelText);
inputLabel.setAttribute("for", "text" + itemId);
groceryItem.appendChild(inputLabel);

/*Create Text Input*/
var textInput = document.createElement("input");
textInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
textInput.style = "display:block";
textInput.id = "text" + itemId;
groceryItem.append(textInput);

/*Create Number Label*/
var numberLabel = document.createElement("label");
var numberlabelText = document.createTextNode("Amount");
numberLabel.appendChild(numberlabelText);
numberLabel.setAttribute("for", "num" + itemId);
groceryItem.appendChild(numberLabel);

/*Create Number Input*/
var numInput = document.createElement("input");
setAttributes(numInput, {"type": "number", "min": "0", "max": "100", "value": "1"});
numInput.style = "display:block";
numInput.id = "num" + itemId;
groceryItem.append(numInput);

/*Remove Grocery Item Button*/
var removeItem = document.createElement("button");
var removeItemText = document.createTextNode("Remove " + itemId);
removeItem.appendChild(removeItemText);
removeItem.id = "remove" + itemId;
removeItem.setAttribute("type","button");
removeItem.setAttribute("onclick","remove(this.parentElement)");
groceryItem.append(removeItem);

/*Add all to form*/
groceryItems.push(groceryItem.innerHTML);
updateIDs();
let lastInArr = groceryItems.slice(-1);
var addField = document.createElement('fieldset');
addField.innerHTML = lastInArr;
groceryList.append(addField);
}

/*?????????????*/
/*Trouble Areas*/
/*?????????????*/
function remove(el){
     groceryItems.splice(el,1);
     groceryList.removeChild(el);
     updateIDs();
}

function updateIDs(){
     id=0;
     for(let i = 0; i < groceryItems.length; i++){
          id = i+1;
     }
     console.log(groceryItems);
}
```

Here's my [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/ineedausernameplease/pen/MWZMKpy).
I apologize if my code is atrocious.

**NOTE** This example is a simplified version of a larger goal, where I would need IDs (or some type of unique identifier) to pair labels with inputs, link inputs with range sliders, get values, display combined values, etc. From what I've been reading, a lot of solutions stray away from the ID approach, but I would still need to use (easily accessible) unique identifiers for the project.

Also, I would prefer pure js, but I can use jQuery if need be.

Comment: I did something similar but rather than change the ids of the existing inputs what I did was find the biggest ID and 1

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do by changing ids on inputs? It smells of a complicated approach to a problem that might have a better solution. What are you doing with the unique identifiers that mandates their usage?

Comment: If you must use ids: why not just track the largest Id? When you have a new element, add one to the largest Id. This way, you aren't trying to re-assign Ids to existing elements. Just always go with LargestId + 1, and update the LargestId with the new value.

Comment: _"The inputs must all have unique IDs"_ - why? The need for an ID to be able to point the labels' `for` attributes to the right field, can be avoided by putting the input field _into_ the label (which automatically associates the label with that input, without the need for any `for` attribute), and "anything else" (accessing elements via script) is often handled better by using classes, and the relationship elements have to each other in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to work well for adding items, but there are issues when it comes to removing and updating the list.

**In my view, there are two potential solutions to address this issue:**

1. **CSS-Only Approach:**
   You can opt for a CSS-only approach, eliminating the need for JavaScript. This approach offers simplicity and avoids the complexity of event listeners and performance concerns. It involves using [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_counter_styles/Using_CSS_counters) with [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements). It's important to note that it comes with cost of accessibility **( just for visual appearance )**.

```html
<section>
  <button onclick="list.addItem()" style="padding: 10px 30px">Add Item</button>
  <form id="groceryList" action="javascript:void(0)"></form>
</section>

<style>
  form {
    counter-reset: div;
  }
  .glist-counter::after {
    counter-increment: div;
    content: counter(div);
  }
</style>

<script>
  class GroceryList {
    #node = null;
    static currentId = 0;
    constructor(nodeSelector) {
      this.#node = document.querySelector(nodeSelector);
    }
    static generateUid() {
      return GroceryList.currentId++;
    }
    static get getUidFormat() {
      return "glist-item-";
    }
    addItem() {
      const id = GroceryList.generateUid();
      const groceryItem = document.createElement("div");
      groceryItem.id = `${GroceryList.getUidFormat}-${id}`;

      groceryItem.innerHTML = `
        <fieldset class="${GroceryList.getUidFormat}">
          <label for="text-${id}" class="glist-counter">Item </label>
          <input type="text" id="text-${id}" style="display: block" />
          <label for="num-${id}">Amount</label>
          <input id="num-${id}" style="display:block" />
          <button id="remove-${id}" type="button" onclick="list.remove(${id})">Remove</button>
        </fieldset>
      `;

      this.#node.appendChild(groceryItem);
    }

    remove(id) {
      this.#node.querySelector(`#${GroceryList.getUidFormat}-${id}`).remove();
    }
  }
  const list = new GroceryList("#groceryList");
</script>
```

2. **JavaScript Solution with Enhanced Accessibility:**
   If you prefer JavaScript and wish to ensure better accessibility, I suggest creating two separate identifiers—one for indexing and the other for input elements. The original solution of updating the IDs of each element may not be the best practice. Instead, consider using a straightforward indexing counter without modifying the attributes.

```html
<section>
  <button id="additem" style="padding: 10px 30px">Add Item</button>
  <form id="groceryList" action="javascript:void(0)"></form>
</section>

<script>
  class GroceryList {
    #node = null;
    static currentId = 0;
    static counter = 0;

    constructor(nodeSelector) {
      this.#node = document.querySelector(nodeSelector);
    }
    static generateUid() {
      return GroceryList.currentId++;
    }
    static get getUidFormat() {
      return "glist-item-";
    }
    addItem() {
      GroceryList.counter++;
      const id = GroceryList.generateUid();
      const groceryItem = document.createElement("div");
      groceryItem.id = `${GroceryList.getUidFormat}-${id}`;

      groceryItem.innerHTML = `
      <fieldset class="${GroceryList.getUidFormat}">
        <label for="text-${id}" class="glist-counter">Item 
          <span class="index-id">${GroceryList.counter}</span>
          </label
        >
        <input type="text" id="text-${id}" style="display: block" />
        <label for="num-${id}">Amount</label>
        <input id="num-${id}" style="display:block" />
        <button id="remove-${id}" type="button">Remove</button>
      </fieldset>
      `;

      // Registering button click event
      groceryItem
        .querySelector("button")
        .addEventListener("click", () => this.remove(id));

      this.#node.appendChild(groceryItem);
    }

    remove(id) {
      this.#node.querySelector(`#${GroceryList.getUidFormat}-${id}`).remove();

      const listItems = this.#node.querySelectorAll(
        `[id^=${GroceryList.getUidFormat}]`
      );

      Array.from(listItems).forEach((item, i) => {
        const spans = item.querySelectorAll(".index-id");
        spans.forEach((el) => (el.textContent = i + 1));
      });

      GroceryList.counter--;
    }
  }
  const list = new GroceryList("#groceryList");

  const addButton = document.querySelector("#additem");
  addButton.addEventListener("click", () => list.addItem());
</script>
```

> Note : I changed the `addItem` to just produce the necessary output .. You can continue with your original plan and implement `setAttribute` function

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your remove function you need to get element to update their id
Here is the javascript code

```js
let id = 0;
let groceryList = document.getElementById("groceryList");
var groceryItems = [];
/*Make it easier to add lots of attrs*/
function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
  for (var key in attrs) {
    el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
  }
}

function addItem() {
  let itemId = "item" + id;
  /*Create Fieldset*/
  var groceryItem = document.createElement("fieldset");
  groceryItem.id = itemId;
  /*Create Label*/
  var inputLabel = document.createElement("label");
  var labelText = document.createTextNode("Item " + id);
  inputLabel.appendChild(labelText);
  inputLabel.setAttribute("for", "text" + itemId);
  groceryItem.appendChild(inputLabel);
  /*Create Text Input*/
  var textInput = document.createElement("input");
  textInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
  textInput.style = "display:block";
  textInput.id = "text" + itemId;
  groceryItem.append(textInput);
  /*Create Number Label*/
  var numberLabel = document.createElement("label");
  var numberlabelText = document.createTextNode("Amount");
  numberLabel.appendChild(numberlabelText);
  numberLabel.setAttribute("for", "num" + itemId);
  groceryItem.appendChild(numberLabel);
  /*Create Number Input*/
  var numInput = document.createElement("input");
  setAttributes(numInput, { type: "number", min: "0", max: "100", value: "1" });
  numInput.style = "display:block";
  numInput.id = "num" + itemId;
  groceryItem.append(numInput);
  /*Remove Grocery Item Button*/
  var removeItem = document.createElement("button");
  var removeItemText = document.createTextNode("Remove " + itemId);
  removeItem.appendChild(removeItemText);
  removeItem.id = "remove" + itemId;
  removeItem.setAttribute("type", "button");
  removeItem.setAttribute("onclick", "remove(this.parentElement)");
  groceryItem.append(removeItem);
  /*Add all to form*/
  groceryItems.push(groceryItem.innerHTML);
  updateIDs();
  let lastInArr = groceryItems.slice(-1);
  var addField = document.createElement("fieldset");
  addField.innerHTML = lastInArr;
  groceryList.append(addField);
}
/*?????????????*/
/*Trouble Areas*/
/*?????????????*/
function remove(el) {
  groceryItems.splice(el, 1);
  groceryList.removeChild(el);
  let element = document.querySelectorAll('fieldset');
  let id = 0;
  element.forEach(item => {
    let newid = id++;
    item.querySelector('input').id = newid;
    item.querySelector('label').textContent = 'Item'+ ' ' + newid;
    item.querySelector('button').textContent = 'Remove item'+ ' ' + newid;
    console.log(item);
  })
  updateIDs();
}
function updateIDs() {
  id = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < groceryItems.length; i++) {
    id = i + 1;
  }
}
```